# Reuse fragment inside AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment (xml and class) that provides a certain functionality, acts as a special value selector with lots of logic.

This fragment is used here and there (in layout files using `<fragment/>`) and now I want to display it as a dialog and allow the user to select a value from there.

This might be trivial, but I haven't found an answer after hours of searching.

I have been playing with `DialogFragment` but I cannot find a way to reuse it inside one. The only I managed to do was to inflate the layout only and display it as a dialog, which is not accepted since the selector logic is missing.

Notes: I am using appCompat if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your current fragment to a `DialogFragment`. DialogFragments can either be embedded or shown as a dialog as explained in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#DialogOrEmbed).

> A DialogFragment can still optionally be used as a normal fragment, if
>   desired. This is useful if you have a fragment that in some cases
>   should be shown as a dialog and others embedded in a larger UI. This
>   behavior will normally be automatically selected for you based on how
>   you are using the fragment, but can be customized with
>   setShowsDialog(boolean).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there a way to add the `DialogFragment` in a layout xml and replace my existing `<fragment/>` elements?

Comment: A `DialogFragment` is a `Fragment` so I would expect it to work and just populate the container with whatever is returned from `onCreateView()` as usual. Did you try it and get any error messages?

Comment: Based on your suggestion I did a little investivation George and I managed to make it work. Thank you. Marking as correct and will post my solution if I find some time later.